# What HTML elements are meant to contain text?

Tags: html, text

What HTML elements are meant or are designed to contain visible text (HTML4/XHTML) ? Planning to make a stylesheet to style them.

Comment: More clarification is always good.
What do you mean by "meant to"? Semantically? Possibility to do so?

Comment: Check the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) for any element that can contain #PCDATA.

Comment: This isn't as bad of a question as the bold yellow area makes it out to be. Writing Semantic HTML is important and some tags should not contain text. Sure, any HTML element can hold a text node but that's not a guideline to live by.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of these are defined as block-type and some as text-level. But they were meant to contain texts (or at least are used as text-wrappers.)

- `<tt>`
- `<i>`
- `<b>`
- `<big>`
- `<small>`
- `<em>`
- `<strong>`
- `<dfn>`
- `<code>`
- `<samp>`
- `<kbd>`
- `<var>`
- `<cite>`
- `<abbr>`
- `<acronym>`
- `<sub>`
- `<sup>`
- `<span>`
- `<bdo>`
- `<address>`
- `<div>`
- `<a>`
- `<object>`
- `<p>`
- `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`
- `<pre>`
- `<q>`
- `<ins>`
- `<del>`
- `<dt>`
- `<dd>`
- `<li>`
- `<label>`
- `<option>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<legend>`
- `<button>`
- `<caption>`
- `<td>`
- `<th>`
- `<title>`
- `<script>`
- `<style>`
- `<blockquote>`

Comment: `<blockquote>` could be also added 

Comment: Added, thanks @MaximeHelen