# How to select all elements containing actual text using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Jsoup saves every text as a textnode including the \r\n stuff in between elements. I want to select all real text on the page and select its parent to remove every text in that parent.

I currently have this:

```
document.select("*:containsOwn(\n)").remove();
    for(int i = 1; i < document.size(); i++){
        if(document.get(i).hasText()){
            List<Element> removableElements = document.get(i).parent().getAllElements();
            for (Element e1 : removableElements) {
                e1.remove();
            }
        }

    }
```

It doesn't remove all the textnodes containing \n so it tries to remove the body as this is the first element which has textnodes in it.

I just want to select all elements with text and do 
*element.parent().children().remove();*

```
document.select("*:contains( )");
```

is also not working the way I want.

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997118/how-to-remove-all-elements-on-text-level-with-jsoup) question but not the same.

**EDIT:**

input:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>some menu item</li>
        <li>some menu item</li>
        <li>some menu item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Tile of some text</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <ul>
        <li>some other text</li>
        <li>some other text</li>
        <li>some other text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

output:

```
<li>some menu item</li>
<li>some menu item</li>
<li>some menu item</li>
<h3>Tile of some text</h3>
<p></p>
<p>some text</p>
<li>some other text</li>
<li>some other text</li>
<li>some other text</li>
```

Comment: Can you add an example of input and expected output?

Comment: `<p></p>` in the output contradicts your rule "containing actual text". This means you have to allow the special case "empty p tag" and since it is probably just an example for more complex websites you will end up with a lot of special cases, since there are a lot of text-level elements http://stackoverflow.com/a/7130146/1661938 Similar problems exist in your related/linked question: you want a general solution, but present a special case. Maybe you should rethink your approach or be much more detailed in describing your target (for example: menu always the same?).

Answer (score 1):

The special case of the empty p tag as part of the intended output (even though it contradicts the rule "containing actual text") requires special parsing. A solution for more complex documents/allowing more empty [text-level elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130079/what-html-elements-are-meant-to-contain-text/7130146#7130146) in the output, would require additional if statements to handle those elements (compare first if statement):

```
String htmlString = "<div><ul><li>some menu item</li><li>some menu item</li><li>some menu item</li></ul></div><div><h3>Tile of some text</h3><p></p><p>some text</p><ul><li>some other text</li><li>some other text</li><li>some other text</li></ul></div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

for (Element element : doc.getAllElements()) {
    if(element.nodeName().equals("p") && element.childNodes().size()==0){
        System.out.println(element.toString());
    }
    else if(element.childNodes().size()>0 && element.childNode(0).nodeName().equals("#text")){
        System.out.println(element.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<li>some menu item</li>
<li>some menu item</li>
<li>some menu item</li>
<h3>Tile of some text</h3>
<p></p>
<p>some text</p>
<li>some other text</li>
<li>some other text</li>
<li>some other text</li>
```